# how to get indication of "success" from removeall

Tags: c#

i want to know if my function did remove from my list or not here is my code:

```
       public int RemovePassenger(string name)
    {

         Passengers.RemoveAll(x => x.PassengerName == name);
        return //if the passenger actually been remove or not 

    }
```

Comment: Could there not be more than 1 passenger with the same name? I think it would make sense if the method took a Passenger Object which it removed from the list rather than a name.

Comment: no,only 1 passenger can be remove at a time

Comment: So what happens if two passengers are called John Smith? Is name a unique field?

Comment: Is the supplied `name` guaranteed to be in the list? If not you will need to be aware you could try to remove a name that never existed and then get a result that implies you had an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return !Passengers.Any(x => x.PassengerName == name);
--- OR ---
return (Passengers.Count(x => x.PassengerName == name) == 0);
```

Because there can be maybe more than one passenger with the same name, I suppose.
Anyway... RemoveAll should not and never fail on what you are doing. You could simply return the result of RemoveAll (the number of removed entries) which could be more useful in the future.

Answer (score 7):

The method returns the number of items removed from the list, so maybe check that. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a.aspx